# Which way to go for a simple "store-retrieve" Java application?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to design a simple Java application. In short I'm trying to build a Book catalog. The main functionality of the "Book catalog" is to register new books, retrieve a book/books that match certain criteria and create print formats also based on the user's criteria.

My issue is that I don't know how to store book objects so that I can retrieve them effectively. I think that there is no need or rather I should avoid using some database since the book catalog concerns only book data.

What do you think I should do in this situation?

Comment: If you're just doing a simple application with relatively few books, you could just store them in-memory using a `Map` or something.

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Do you need to persist your books between runs of your application? What kind of search criteria do you have? Do you have actual books (e.g., PDFs stored as files), or just attributes of each book?

Comment: So many [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+what%27s+the+best+way+book+catalogue&rlz=1C1ASUT_enUS496CA496&oq=java+what%27s+the+best+way+book+catalogue&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i59j69i60l3.9781j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=java+what%27s+the+best+way+save+data+to+a+file+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)... did you look before asking?

Comment: I think it's better to use some DBMS. there are many open-source/free options.
For simple application i'd recommend [HSQL] (hsqldb.org) which can be configured as standalone server or in-memory.

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the book class and ergo the filter criteria. Are you planning on different kind of books/inheritance? You could even simply write them into properties.

Comment: Hi i though of map as well but  in retrieve i may need to use any or multiple attributes as keys to get the object , is that possible?

Comment: The book class will have 5-6 attributes, strings , integer , a date, no custom objects. Also you are right about my question not being explained in detail, thanks for making the effort to help me.

Comment: Do you want to store data on disk, or just hold it in memory while the program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably just implementing the Serializable interface and writing it to a file.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57

If you want to write it in a readable format, you should probably look into JSON or XML.

Comment: Ended up implementing the serializable interface and i think it works really good for what i wanted to do, thank you.